# Cast a Python class to Numpy Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-dataclasses

Can I cast a python class to a numpy `array`?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np
@dataclass
class X:
    x: float = 0
    y: float = 0
x = X()
x_array = np.array(x) # would like to get an numpy array np.array([X.x,X.y])
```

In the last step, I would like the to obtain an array `np.array([X.x, X.y])`. Instead, I get `array(X(x=0, y=0), dtype=object)`.

Can I provide method for the `dataclass` so that the casting works as desired (or overload one of the existing methods of the `dataclass`)?

Comment: try to add `def __iter__(self): yield from (self.x, self.y)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @AzatIbrakov ! I did try but to no avail. Maybe I defined it the wrong way. Can you provide a fully specified answer?

Comment: it was a wrong suggestion based only on intuition, after reading a docstring of `numpy.array` it is clear that you can define `__array__` method like `def __array__(self): return np.array([self.x, self.y])`

Comment: Thanks @AzatIbrakov ! This is really helpful.  Do you want to write an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [docstring of `numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) we can see requirements for the first parameter

> `object`: `array_like`
>
> An array, any object exposing the array interface,
> an object whose `__array__` method returns an array, or any
> (nested) sequence.

So we can define an `__array__` method like

```py
@dataclass
class X:
    x: float = 0
    y: float = 0

    def __array__(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.array([self.x, self.y])
```

and it will be used by `np.array`. This should work for any custom Python class I guess.